# How to ignore letters big or small?

Tags: php, strpos

My code is:

```
if (strpos($var1, 'lemon' ) !== false){
    $var2 = "No.";
}
```

variable `var1` is text from a text box.

How do I ignore case?

Comment: Are you talking about type case? So upper and lower case letters?

Answer (score 3):

As this looks like PHP, you'll probably like  [stripos](http://php.net/stripos). For future reference, a comparison ignoring "letters big or small" is called a *case insensitive* comparison.